# How to pass table type in oracle using python(cx_oracle or oracledb)

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, python-oracledb

i want to pass table type in call_proc using python.

But i'm getting error while running.

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'REPORT_P'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
```

```
PROCEDURE report_p
    (
        OUT_details     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
        IN_col      IN col,
        IN_com  IN  VARCHAR2,
        IN_id       IN NUMBER
    )
```

```
create or replace TYPE col AS OBJECT
(
    name        VARCHAR2(4000),
    mn        VARCHAR2(4000),
    fil    VARCHAR2(4000)

);
```

my code

```
out_val = cur.var(oracledb.CURSOR)
cur.callproc("report_p",(out_val,[],"Radio",21222))
```

Comment: This appears to be covered in the documentation: [Changing Bind Data Types using an Input Type Handler](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#changing-bind-data-types-using-an-input-type-handler)

Comment: Also, you are not passing a table type. It is an object.

Answer (score 3):

To pass an object like `col` you need to create one first. Something like this:

```py
typ = conn.gettype("COL")
obj = typ.newobject()
obj.NAME = "NAME value"
obj.MN = "MN value"
obj.FIL = "FIL value"
ref_cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.callproc("report_p", [ref_cursor, obj, "Radio", 21222])
```